# VS2010: Bad IL Range error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005

I'm attempting to connect to a database via the "Add Connection" in VS2010.  The database is running SQL2005, and is accessible in VS2008.   When I attempt to connect in VS2010 I receive the following error:

> Unable to add data connection.
> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
> Bad IL range.

Oddly the "Test connection" works fine. 
I've attempted to re-initialize VS2010 via the registry with no luck. Am looking for any suggestions as to the cause, or where I can look next, to find the root cause.

Additional Info
I have noticed in the system event log 2 errors when I attempt to attach to a database: 
1) The following fatal alert was generated: 48. The internal error state is 552.  and 
2) The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an untrusted certificate authority. Because of this, none of the data contained in the certificate can be validated. The SSL connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate.

I've attempted to uninstall and re-install VS2010. No luck.  Attempting to connect on another machine seems to work, but my main development machine continues to fail with the error(s) noted above.   I'd prefer not to have to reformat my machine, and am desperate to find an answer or reasonable course of action to find the problem...  help!

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning your application and rebuilding usually resolves this issue.